# Input fields inside Angular-Ui Tabs are not POSTing to DB

Tags: angularjs

I have a Angular modal that has Angular-UI tabs. The input fields outside the tabs POST fine, Input fields inside the tabs are not. However I use the same modal for PUT and that modal updates the DB with new data. Is this a scope issue?

```
  <fieldset>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                @*<label style="">Hide:&nbsp;</label>
                                    <input style="" ng-model="currentItem.JobHidden" type="checkbox">*@
                                <div class="inline-fields">
                                    <h4 style="margin-left:24px">Job Info&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Customer Info</h4>
                                    <label style="margin-left:23px">Number:</label>
                                    <input style="width:100px" ng-model="JobNumber" type="text">

                                    <label style="margin-left:115px">Customer:</label>
                                    <input style="width:150px" type="text" ng-model="CustomerName"
                                           typeahead="customer.CustomerName for customer in customerArray | filter:$viewValue"
                                           placeholder="Enter Customer" typeahead-on-select="selectNewCustomer($item)">
                                </div>
                                <div class="inline-fields">
                                    <label style="margin-left:33px">Status:</label>
                                    <select style="width: 100px" ng-model="JobStatus">
                                        <option disabled>Select</option>
                                        <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                        <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
                                        <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <label style="margin-left:125px">Address:</label>
                                    <input style="width:200px" ng-model="CustomerAddress" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="inline-fields">
                                    <label style="margin-left:38px">Name:</label>
                                    <input style="width:150px" ng-model="JobName" type="text">
                                    <label style="margin-left:104px">City:</label>
                                    <input style="width: 66px" ng-model="CustomerCity" type="text">

                                    <label>St:</label>
                                    <input style="width: 30px" ng-model="CustomerState" type="text">

                                    <label>Zip:</label>
                                    <input style="width: 44px" ng-model="CustomerZipcode" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="inline-fields">
                                    <label style="margin-left:20px">Address:</label>
                                    <input style="width:185px" ng-model="JobAddress" type="text">
                                    <label style="margin-left:78px">Ph:</label>
                                    <input style="width: 100px; " ng-model="CustomerPhoneNumber" type="text">

                                    <label style="margin-left:0px">Fax:</label>
                                    <input style="width: 89px" ng-model="CustomerFaxNumber" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="inline-fields">
                                    <label style="margin-left:49px">City:</label>
                                    <input style="width:66px" ng-model="JobCity" type="text">

                                    <label>St:</label>
                                    <input style="width:30px" ng-model="JobState" type="text">

                                    <label>Zip:</label>
                                    <input style="width:44px" ng-model="JobZipcode" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="inline-fields">
                                    <label style="margin-left:58px">Ph:</label>
                                    <input style="width:100px" ng-model="JobPhoneNumber" type="text">

                                    <label>Fax:</label>
                                    <input style="width:89px" ng-model="JobFaxNumber" type="text">

                                </div>
                                <div class="inline-fields">
                                    <label style="margin-left:55px">PM:</label>
                                    <select style="width:138px" ng-options="employee.EmployeeFirstName + ' ' + employee.EmployeeLastName as employee.EmployeeFirstName + ' ' + employee.EmployeeLastName for employee in employeeArray | filter:{EmployeeIsPM : true}" ng-model="JobTESPM">
                                        <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset><br />



                        <!--Cover Content-->
                        <tabset>
                            <tab heading="Contract">
                                <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:10px">
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left:13px">Original&nbsp;Contract:</label>
                                        <input style="width:115px" ng-model="JobOriginalContract" type="text" format="number">

                                        <label style="margin-left:57px">Geo&nbsp;Area:</label>
                                        <select style="width: 115px" ng-model="JobGeoArea">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="JobGeoArea-1">JobGeoArea-1</option>
                                            <option value="JobGeoArea-2">JobGeoArea-2</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left:69px">Total&nbsp;CO:</label>
                                        <input style="width:115px" ng-model="JobTotalCO" type="text" format="number">
                                        <label style="margin-left:82px">Job&nbsp;Class:</label>
                                        <select style="width: 115px; " ng-model="JobClass">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="JobClass-1">JobClass-1</option>
                                            <option value="JobClass-2">JobClass-2</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left:11px">Revised&nbsp;Contract:</label>
                                        <input style="width:115px" ng-model="JobRevisedContract" type="text" format="number">
                                        <label style="margin-left:55px">Min&nbsp;Wage:</label>
                                        <select style="width:90px" ng-model="JobMinWage">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="1000">$1000</option>
                                            <option value="2000">$2000</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <label style="margin-left:0px">Job&nbsp;Type:</label>
                                        <select style="width: 90px" ng-model="JobType">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="JobType-1">JobType</option>
                                            <option value="JobType-2">JobType</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left:59px">Retainage:</label>
                                        <select style="width:115px" ng-model="JobRetainage">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="JobRetainage-1">JobRetainage-1</option>
                                            <option value="JobRetainage-2">JobRetainage-2</option>
                                            <option value="JobRetainage-3">JobRetainage-3</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <label style="margin-left:42px">Tax&nbsp;Exempt:</label>
                                        <select style="width: 115px" ng-model="JobTaxExempt">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="true">True</option>
                                            <option value="false">False</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left:21px">Original&nbsp;Budget:</label>
                                        <input style="width:115px" ng-model="JobOriginalBudget" type="text" format="number">

                                        <label style="margin-left:39px">Ins&nbsp;Program:</label>
                                        <select style="width: 115px" ng-model="JobInsProgram">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="JobInsProgram-1">JobInsProgram-1</option>
                                            <option value="JobInsProgram-2">JobInsProgram-2</option>
                                            <option value="JobInsProgram-3">JobInsProgram-3</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--End col-xs-12-->
                            </tab><!--End Contract Tab-->

                            <tab heading="Contacts">Contacts go here</tab>
                            <tab heading="Document Distribution">Document Distribution go here</tab>
                        </tabset><!--End Tab Content-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input style="margin-left:345px;width:70px;margin-right:20px;margin-top:25px" ng-click="printNewJobModal(currentItem)" type="button" value="Print" go-click="#" />&nbsp;
                            <input style="margin-right: 20px; width: 70px; margin-top: 25px" type="submit" value="Save" go-click="#" />
                            <input style="width: 70px; margin-top: 25px" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" value="Exit" go-click="#" />
                        </div>

 //New Job Modal
$scope.NewJobModal = function () {
    $ekathuwa.modal({
        id: "NewJobModal", contentStyle: "width:800px;heigth:400px",
        scope: $scope,
        templateURL: "ModalNewJob"
    });
}
//Post New Job
$scope.submitJob = function () {
    var data = {
        JobId: $scope.JobId,
        JobNumber: $scope.JobNumber,
        JobName: $scope.JobName,
        JobDescription: $scope.JobDescription,
        JobOriginalContract: $scope.JobOriginalContract,
        JobBillingDate: $scope.JobBillingDate,
        JobTotalCO: $scope.JobTotalCO,
        JobRevisedContract: $scope.JobRevisedContract,
        JobOriginalBudget: $scope.JobOriginalBudget,
        JobBillingForm: $scope.JobBillingForm,
        JobTESPM: $scope.JobTESPM,
        JobTESSuperintendent: $scope.JobTESSuperintendent,
        JobStatus: $scope.JobStatus,
        JobMoreShit: $scope.JobMoreShit,
        JobHidden: $scope.JobHidden,
        JobTaxExempt: $scope.JobTaxExempt,
        JobCertPayroll: $scope.JobCertPayroll,
        JobCost: $scope.JobCost,
        JobRemainingBudget: $scope.JobRemainingBudget,
        JobProfit: $scope.JobProfit,
        JobPercentage: $scope.JobPercentage,
        JobTotalBilled: $scope.JobTotalBilled,
        JobBalanceToBill: $scope.JobBalanceToBill,
        JobBalanceDue: $scope.JobBalanceDue,
        JobAddress: $scope.JobAddress,
        JobCity: $scope.JobCity,
        JobState: $scope.JobState,
        JobZipcode: $scope.JobZipcode,
        JobCounty: $scope.JobCounty,
        JobPhoneNumber: $scope.JobPhoneNumber,
        JobFaxNumber: $scope.JobFaxNumber,

        JobGeoArea: $scope.JobGeoArea,
        JobClass: $scope.JobClass,
        JobType: $scope.JobType,
        JobMinWage: $scope.JobMinWage,
        JobInsProgram: $scope.JobInsProgram,

        CustomerName: $scope.CustomerName,
        CustomerPhoneNumber: $scope.CustomerPhoneNumber,
        CustomerFaxNumber: $scope.CustomerFaxNumber,
        CustomerAddress: $scope.CustomerAddress,
        CustomerCity: $scope.CustomerCity,
        CustomerState: $scope.CustomerState,
        CustomerZipcode: $scope.CustomerZipcode,
        CustomerWebsite: $scope.CustomerWebsite,
        CustomerOtherShit: $scope.CustomerOtherShit,
        CustomerHidden: $scope.CustomerHidden,
        CustomerPM: $scope.CustomerPM,
        CustomerAdmin: $scope.CustomerAdmin,
        CustomerAccountant: $scope.CustomerAccountant,
        CustomerSuperintendent: $scope.CustomerSuperintendent
    }
    $http.post('/api/apiJob/PostNewJob', data).success(function (data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data); window.top.location.reload();
    });
```

Updated Controller

```
//Post New Job
$scope.submitJob = function () {
    var data = {
        JobId: $scope.JobId,
        JobNumber: $scope.JobNumber,
        JobName: $scope.JobName,
        JobDescription: $scope.JobDescription,
        JobOriginalContract: $scope.JobOriginalContract.Value,
        JobBillingDate: $scope.JobBillingDate,
        JobTotalCO: $scope.JobTotalCO.Value,
        JobRevisedContract: $scope.JobRevisedContract.Value,
        JobOriginalBudget: $scope.JobOriginalBudget.Value,
        JobBillingForm: $scope.JobBillingForm,
        JobTESPM: $scope.JobTESPM,
        JobTESSuperintendent: $scope.JobTESSuperintendent,
        JobStatus: $scope.JobStatus,
        JobMoreShit: $scope.JobMoreShit,
        JobHidden: $scope.JobHidden,
        JobTaxExempt: $scope.JobTaxExempt.Value,
        JobCertPayroll: $scope.JobCertPayroll,
        JobCost: $scope.JobCost,
        JobRemainingBudget: $scope.JobRemainingBudget,
        JobProfit: $scope.JobProfit,
        JobPercentage: $scope.JobPercentage,
        JobTotalBilled: $scope.JobTotalBilled,
        JobBalanceToBill: $scope.JobBalanceToBill,
        JobBalanceDue: $scope.JobBalanceDue,
        JobAddress: $scope.JobAddress,
        JobCity: $scope.JobCity,
        JobState: $scope.JobState,
        JobZipcode: $scope.JobZipcode,
        JobCounty: $scope.JobCounty,
        JobPhoneNumber: $scope.JobPhoneNumber,
        JobFaxNumber: $scope.JobFaxNumber,

        JobGeoArea: $scope.JobGeoArea.Value,
        JobClass: $scope.JobClass.Value,
        JobType: $scope.JobType.Value,
        JobMinWage: $scope.JobMinWage.Value,
        JobInsProgram: $scope.JobInsProgram.Value,

        CustomerName: $scope.CustomerName,
        CustomerPhoneNumber: $scope.CustomerPhoneNumber,
        CustomerFaxNumber: $scope.CustomerFaxNumber,
        CustomerAddress: $scope.CustomerAddress,
        CustomerCity: $scope.CustomerCity,
        CustomerState: $scope.CustomerState,
        CustomerZipcode: $scope.CustomerZipcode,
        CustomerWebsite: $scope.CustomerWebsite,
        CustomerOtherShit: $scope.CustomerOtherShit,
        CustomerHidden: $scope.CustomerHidden,
        CustomerPM: $scope.CustomerPM,
        CustomerAdmin: $scope.CustomerAdmin,
        CustomerAccountant: $scope.CustomerAccountant,
        CustomerSuperintendent: $scope.CustomerSuperintendent
    }
    $http.post('/api/apiJob/PostNewJob', data).success(function (data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data); window.top.location.reload();
    });

};
```

Updated View

```
<tab heading="Contract">
                                <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:10px">
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left:13px">Original&nbsp;Contract:</label>
                                        <input style="width:115px" ng-model="JobOriginalContract.Value" type="text" format="number">

                                        <label style="margin-left:57px">Geo&nbsp;Area:</label>
                                        <select style="width: 115px" ng-model="JobGeoArea.Value">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="JobGeoArea-1">JobGeoArea-1</option>
                                            <option value="JobGeoArea-2">JobGeoArea-2</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left:69px">Total&nbsp;CO:</label>
                                        <input style="width:115px" ng-model="JobTotalCO.Value" type="text" format="number">
                                        <label style="margin-left:82px">Job&nbsp;Class:</label>
                                        <select style="width: 115px; " ng-model="JobClass.Value">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="JobClass-1">JobClass-1</option>
                                            <option value="JobClass-2">JobClass-2</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left:11px">Revised&nbsp;Contract:</label>
                                        <input style="width:115px" ng-model="JobRevisedContract.Value" type="text" format="number">
                                        <label style="margin-left:55px">Min&nbsp;Wage:</label>
                                        <select style="width:90px" ng-model="JobMinWage.Value">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="1000">$1000</option>
                                            <option value="2000">$2000</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <label style="margin-left:0px">Job&nbsp;Type:</label>
                                        <select style="width: 90px" ng-model="JobType.Value">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="JobType-1">JobType</option>
                                            <option value="JobType-2">JobType</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left:59px">Retainage:</label>
                                        <select style="width:115px" ng-model="JobRetainage.Value">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="JobRetainage-1">JobRetainage-1</option>
                                            <option value="JobRetainage-2">JobRetainage-2</option>
                                            <option value="JobRetainage-3">JobRetainage-3</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <label style="margin-left:42px">Tax&nbsp;Exempt:</label>
                                        <select style="width: 115px" ng-model="JobTaxExempt.Value">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="true">True</option>
                                            <option value="false">False</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left:21px">Original&nbsp;Budget:</label>
                                        <input style="width:115px" ng-model="JobOriginalBudget.Value" type="text" format="number">

                                        <label style="margin-left:39px">Ins&nbsp;Program:</label>
                                        <select style="width: 115px" ng-model="JobInsProgram.Value">
                                            <option disabled>Select</option>
                                            <option value="JobInsProgram-1">JobInsProgram-1</option>
                                            <option value="JobInsProgram-2">JobInsProgram-2</option>
                                            <option value="JobInsProgram-3">JobInsProgram-3</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--End col-xs-12-->
                            </tab><!--End Contract Tab-->

};
```

Comment: Yes it is scope issue, always have a dot in `ng-model` so you aren't using primitive variables.

Comment: I added .Value to the ng-models. but now I am getting a error message "Cannot read property 'Value' of undefined.  see updated post

Comment: making far more work than you need to, use same object for whole form, then don't need to declare all the properties in `data`, just pass whole object to `post`. `Job.JobID, Job.JobName` etc. `ng-model` will create all the properties for you, just define `$scope.Job={}`

Comment: can you show me please in script file   http://plnkr.co/edit/rLOAcfGPW0AXmVEpP09h?p=preview

Comment: see if this crude demo helps  http://plnkr.co/edit/YmdMXFdHDNXX33l5343q

Comment: Updated the plunkr    I am getting error message, ReferenceError: JOB is not defined

Comment: not sure what you updated, was working fine in my simple demo

Comment: not sure either, Ive tripled checked to see I did it the same way. for now I just went back to the bootstrap modal. thanks though